# Inspecting nested Standard Library data

Tags: c++, stl, gdb, g++

I'm using ddd 3.3.11 and gdb 6.5-8.fc6rh underneath it. My compiler is g++ 4.1.1.

I have a stl map container, containing as its key lookup a vector of int's (vector).
The data at the key is of `MyType*`.

I'm using the .gdbinit file as written by Dan Marinescu. It works great, until you nest your C++ Standard Library containers.

My question is, using the inspection techniques as exampled in the .gdbinit file,
is there a way to inspect nested stdlib data?

The main problem I'm running into appears to be when the .gdbinit file attempts to typecast.

If my map is of type

```
 map<vector<int>, MyType*>
```

Then, in gdb, I try a pmap call such as

```
pmap myMap vector<int> MyType*
```

This fails with

```
elem[0].left: No symbol "vector<int>" in current context.
```

What syntax is it in gdb I must use to typecast some data to a templated type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a more recent gdb, I had to add single-quotes, as well as adding namespaces, and an allocator.

```
(gdb) pmap myMap 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>' MyType*
elem[0].left: $3 = std::vector of length 1, capacity 1 = {2}
elem[0].right: $4 = (MyType *) 0x7fffffffe060
Map size = 1
```